# Turn an array of date strings into dates

Tags: python, datetime

I have an array of date strings `['1/1/2014', '1/2/2014', '1/3/2014', ...]`, how do I turn that into an array of Date objects?

This will cast 1 cell:

```
time.strptime(dates[1], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

But I haven't seen a way to pass in an entire array. I can loop over my array:

```
date_objects = []
for date in dates:
    date_objects.append(time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
end
```

Gives an error that `ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: Your code works in my machine using Python 2.7 and I delete the last line 'end'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and call [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to get `datetime.date` objects:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> l = ['1/1/2014', '1/2/2014', '1/3/2014']
>>> [datetime.strptime(item, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for item in l]
[datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 1, 2), datetime.date(2014, 1, 3)]
```